# Boost Pool Library: How to reuse created objects?

Tags: c++, boost, memory-management, reusability, boost-pool

So at the beginning of my program I want  to create some buffer array on some 3 costume data elements (structs of chars and there length for example). I want to pass out from my app first  than second element etc after all 3 elements were taken into use I want to get first one and than second etc... so not to malloc memory for elements again. Is it possible [with Boost Pool Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/pool/doc/interfaces.html) and how exactly to do such thing?

Answer (score 1):

maybe boost::circular_buffer can do such job